# Build a dictionary from successful regex matches in python

Tags: python, regex, iterable, dictionary-comprehension

I'm pretty new to Python, and I'm trying to parse a file. Only certain lines in the file contain data of interest, and I want to end up with a dictionary of the stuff parsed from valid matching lines in the file.

The code below works, but it's a bit ugly and I'm trying to learn how it should be done, perhaps with a comprehension, or else with a multiline regex.  I'm using Python 3.2.

```
file_data = open('x:\\path\\to\\file','r').readlines()
my_list = []
for line in file_data:
    # discard lines which don't match at all
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        # icky, repeating search!!
        one_tuple = re.search(pattern, line).group(3,2)
        my_list.append(one_tuple)
my_dict = dict(my_list)
```

Can you suggest a better implementation?

Comment: Comprehensions can be pretty, but you can't easily bind a variable to a value inside them, so you'd need the double `re.search`. Just use a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.  After putting them together I got

```
file_data = open('x:\\path\\to\\file','r').read()
my_list = re.findall(pattern, file_data, re.MULTILINE)
my_dict = {c:b for a,b,c in my_list}
```

but I don't think I could have gotten there today without the help.

Comment: You might want to make the first group in you regex non-capturing (`?:`) to skip the comprehension step: `my_dict = dict(re.findall...)`

Comment: Pretty good improvement. However: reading all the data into a variable, rather than iterating over a file object (and implicitly calling `readline()` method), is not very scalable. `re.findall()` works perfectly well on an iterator rather than a variable.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some quick'n'dirty optimisations to your code:

```
my_dict = dict()

with open(r'x:\path\to\file', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            one_tuple = match.group(3, 2)
            my_dict[one_tuple[0]] = one_tuple[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) I'd suggest

```
with open(r'x:\path\to\file', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        try:
            m = re.search(pattern, line)
            my_dict[m.group(2)] = m.group(3)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Another way is to keep using lists, but redesign the pattern so that it contains only two groups `(key, value)`. Then you could simply do:

```
  matches = [re.findall(pattern, line) for line in data]
  mydict = dict(x[0] for x in matches if x)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
matchRes = pattern.match(line)
if matchRes:
    my_dict = matchRes.groupdict()
```

Comment: Please, follow your code snippet with some details, explanations to be more clear for readers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd recommend it, but here's a way you could try to use a comprehension instead(I substituted a string for the file for simplicity)

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """1foo bar
... 2bing baz
... 3spam eggs
... nomatch
... """
>>> pattern = r"(.)(\w+)\s(\w+)"
>>> {x[0]: x[1] for x in (m.group(3, 2) for m in (re.search(pattern, line) for line in data.splitlines()) if m)}
{'baz': 'bing', 'eggs': 'spam', 'bar': 'foo'}
```

Comment: Dict comprehension; I like it!